# In Laravel 6, how to define a custom menu when working without a database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

We are using Laravel 6 for a small website and dont use a database for it. I could not find any hints on where to define a custom menu. In my understanding it would be a good idea to create a component or view that just lists all the available routes and renders them as an unordered list, for instance. I then would include that view in my header blade template.

Using something like `{{ Route::getRoutes() }}` inside a blade template didnt work.

Comment: "*Using something like `{{ Route::getRoutes() }}` inside a blade template didn't work*" - No, I wouldn't expect that to work at all. `Route::getRoutes()` returns a `RouteCollection`; you'd need to loop over the routes in that and output a `<li>` element (or similar) for each.

Comment: @TimLewis I guessed so, but I have a hard time finding documentation on this. Can you provide some further links to dig into? Thanks

Comment: Takes a bit of digging into the components API, but that's available here: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_getRoutes, https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html#method_getRoutes and https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_uri. The actual call would be `@foreach(Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() AS $route) <li>{{ $route->uri }}</li> @endforeach` (or similar). Have to double the `->getRoutes()` call in Laravel 5.2+

Comment: @TimLewis thanks! it works. do you have a hint on how to load only the custom routes? it also loads internal/ ignition routes.

Comment: Could do some string matching, or if your custom routes are named, match them against https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_named, etc. Do you have too many routes that you can't hard code the URLs? Writing a bunch of `<li><a href="{{ url('/whatever') }}">Example</a></li>` isn't too hard generally. (replace with `route('name')` if using named routes)

Comment: @TimLewis im always a friend of dynamically writing the things instead of hardcoding, but in this case maybe thats better. still, i wonder how you would do it. will look into the docs, thanks again

Comment: Haha yeah, I agree in practice, but depends on the scope of effort. If it's going to take loading all the routes, filtering out the unneeded ones, then displaying them, it might not be worth it for only a handful of routes. But yeah, play with it a bit more, and if you come up with a solution, feel free to post it :)